# Variable changing in "original" object after passing to another form/object and being changed there

Tags: c#, object

I'm experiencing something strange in my project. One of my object values appears to be changing despite there being no code in the form it was created that would change the value.

This object is, however, passed to another form where the variable is indeed being changed. Am I misunderstanding how objects passed to other objects/forms work in the sense that its not a copy but a link to the original from (potentially) several layers down?

Comment: Essential reading: [Value Types and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, objects (instances) are references to each new template of their class. passing objects therefore means passing the pointer or reference.
sort of opposite would be a struct, which is a value type there you pass the whole struct on the stack.

Comment: so even though the object is never passed back to the original location, any value changes made to any instance of that object would filter both forwards and backwards depending where in the "chain" it was?

Comment: now it gets confusing. instance of an object? you instantiate a new object from a class. you pass this object (by ref) to another form. if this form changes properties of the instance, they are also changed in the creating scope, because it is the same instance(=object). No idea what you mean with filter and forward/backward. try some example code.

Comment: Form 1 creates object, passes to Form 2 which uses the data then passes to Form 3 (imagine a series of windows) If the object values were changed at any point (eg, Form 3 calls a method inside Form 2 that changes the value) would that change filter to the other forms?

Comment: I don't understand 'filter' in that case?

Comment: If you mean forwarding, then yes! all your forms are working on the *same* object! You would even get into trouble with some concurrency if you are reading and writing in parallel to the same object without locking.

Comment: Looks like a language barrier :D. Yes, thats exactly what I meant. Thanks for clearing that up, i can now stop smashing my head against the desk